# Embedded linux - sysfs - disable pwm pin without disabling the whole channel

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, sysfs

I have a raspberry pi, I want to use one single pwm channel to control a rgb led. There are 2 pins available for pwm0. So I connected red led on first pin and green led on second pin. I connected the blue one on a gpio. When I enable pwm0, the red and green leds are on. I would like to control them individually. I know it will be same period and duty cycle but is there a way to turn one pin off without disabling the entire pwm channel  ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information, such as a code snippet, the library you are using and the schematic. You can find more information on this specific stackexchange thread for raspberry: [PWM on Raspberry](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/298/can-i-use-the-gpio-for-pulse-width-modulation-pwm). You must be having trouble configuring your pins. For sure, you are able to do it.